# Chromium debugger : how to check radio input

Tags: html, chromium, javascript-debugger

How can I toggle a `:checked` state to a `<input type="radio">` in Chromium debugger tools?

Here's how my `input` is rendered:

```
<input type="radio" id="card-14" ng-model="cardInfo.id" ng-value="creditCard.id" required="" class="ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse" name="53" value="14">
```

I thought adding a `<input checked />` attribute or `checked="checked"` used to work but apparently not anymore.

It cannot be toggled in the state toggler either...

[image]

Ain't this possible anymore?

Comment: It should work like this. I can only assume that AngularJS does some magic and immediately unchecks the radiobutton again. You could (assuming you have the latest Chromium/Chrome which shows `== $0` next to selected elements) also try clicking on the element in the elements tab and then entering `$0.checked = true;` in the console.

Comment: I thought the difficulty might be angular-related, but: 1. even the actual `checked` one hasn't any property while I thought Angular was always rendering to regular DOM description 2. I thought Angular wouldn't trigger a `$digest` cycle for any debugger interaction, which means Angular *shouldn't* know about me editing. But if you say this is the actual behavior, all this might be wrong :(

Comment: I am not sure about what Angular does there, but the thing is that if I copy your radio button into JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f788gob0/2/), open devtools and use "Add attribute" to add `checked` (or `checked="checked"`, no difference), it gets checked and jumps to the right due to the CSS rule I added.